# Accessing the value of an input element with XPath in an XSLT

Tags: xslt, dom, xhtml, xpath, input

I'm developing a web app for Firefox that has a button that triggers a client-side XSLT transformation of the document's DOM, with a stylesheet fetched via AJAX.

Here's a portion of the XHTML that's going to be transformed:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Static Javascript-based XMR Form Creator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="title">Static Javascript-based XMR Form Creator</h1>

    <div class="opt_block" id="main_opts">
        Form name <input type="text" id="form_name" />
        Form cols <input type="text" id="form_cols" size="3" maxlength="3" />
    </div>
    <button id="generate">Generate source</button>
    <textarea rows="20" cols="50" id="xmr_source" ></textarea>
</body>
```

Inside the stylesheet, I want to access the `value` attribute of the first input field, the one with id `form_name`.

The XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/html/body/div[@id = 'main_opts']" >
    <form>
        <xsl:attribute name="fname">
            <xsl:value-of select="input[@id = 'form_name']/@value" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </form>
</xsl:template>
```

I apply the XSLT on the *current* `document`, like so:

```
var processor = new XSLTProcessor();
processor.importStylesheet(data); // data received via AJAX request
// document is obviously the object representing the current DOM
var result = processor.transformToDocument(document);
```

The problem is that the XPath that should do the work:

```
<xsl:value-of select="input[@id = 'form_name']/@value" />
```

returns nothing, whereas inspecting the DOM via Firebug shows the `input` element's `value` property does have a value.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT: made clear that the XSLT is applied to the current document**

Comment: Does that mean you add the form value manually (because the input you show does not have one)?

Comment: it may seem hackish, but there's no form element. i only use the `input` and `textarea` elements for what they do, without actually ever sending a form.

Comment: If you try to get the value of the "type" attribute, does it work? 

(I want to eliminate the possibility that it's a namespace oddity you're seeing, as your XSLT doesn't use the standard html namespace, whereas your HTML -- which doesn't appear to be valid XHTML -- may be gaining one somewhere.)

Comment: yes, it works, and it also correctly gets the default value attribute, if i specify one in the html.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Looks to me as if it's nothing to do with XSL -- the "document" object itself doesn't have the value changed/added at the time you run transformDocument on it, would be my guess. Unfortunately, that makes it more of a JavaScript problem, and out of my main field.

Comment: actually, the value is correctly set in the document object, as i can retrieve it with pure javascript (getElementById and so forth). the problem lies in the fact that the XPath doesn't seem to be able to get these live values..

Comment: Then I can't really see any reason that the XPath would retrieve the "type" rather than the "value", unless maybe when the "value" is created dynamically, it's being placed in a different namespace. 

You could try declaring the correct namespace for your XHTML document (http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml) and making sure it validates as XHTML, which it won't at the moment; that might help.

Answer (score 1):

try referencing the input with a slash or dot dot slash

```
<xsl:value-of select="/input[@id = 'form_name']/@value" />
<xsl:value-of select="../input[@id = 'form_name']/@value" />
```

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't seem to be the problem

Answer (score 1):

**One obvious problem:**

```
<xsl:value-of select="input[@id = 'form_name']/@value" />
```

This must output the value of the `@value` attribute of the `input` child of the vurrent node.

**However**, in the provided XML document, the `input` child of the element matched by the template, doesn't have a `@value` attribute:

```
   Form name <input type="text" id="form_name" />
```

The only two attributes this `input` element has are `type` and `id`.

**Solution**: Add a `value` attribute to the input element and (given everything else in the XSLT code works OK), the value of this attribute should be output.

**For example use**:

```
   Form name <input type="text" id="form_name" value="XXXXX" />
```

Comment: But the `value` attribute of an `input` element specifies its *initial* value. I, OTOH, want to get its current one.
If i query the DOM for the whole `input` element, instead of just its `@value`, in Javascript and then get its value property, everything works, which means that the DOM representation of that element *does* hold its current value in the `value` property. So why doesn't it work with pure XPath?

Comment: Also, if I do as you say, all I get is the `input` element's initial value, instead of the current one.

Comment: @asymmetric: XPath doesn't know anything about how a browser handles the HTML DOM. What you want cannot be achieved by evaluating an XPath expression, unless the *current* XML Document (DOM) is provided to the XPath engine.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing :)
I process the `document` DOM object passing it as an argument to the `XSLTProcessor.transformToDocument` method.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack, but I use it and it works

Add

```
onBlur="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);"
```

to every input element.

You can use whatever event you want but onBlur is nice, since it does not generate too much client side overhead.